# Добавление нового модуля

Tags: lsfusion

Создал новый модуль, добавил в проект, но не вижу никаких изменений. При запуске сервера этот новый модуль не инициализируется (смотрел в start.log). Нужно ли его как-то прописывать в конфигурации проекта, или он должен подхватиться автоматически?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте разберемся, как сервер ищет модули:

1. Сначала учитываются [параметры запуска](https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/Launch_parameters/#applsfusion) `logics.includePaths` и `logics.excludePaths`. Первый определяет список путей, по которым будет осуществляться поиск .lsf файлов. Второй - наоборот, список путей, которые должны быть исключены из поиска.

   Если `logics.includePaths` не задан, то его значение по умолчанию будет `*`, что будет соответствовать `classpath` запускаемого сервера, который в свою очередь по умолчанию будет текущей директорией, где запускается jvm. Если `logics.exludePaths` не задан, то его значением будет пустой список.

   В результате получится набор путей, по которым будет осуществлен поиск .lsf файлов.
2. Затем учитывается параметр запуска `logics.topModule`. Его значением должно быть имя специального "верхнего" модуля (обратите внимание, что именно имя модуля, а не файла). Если этот параметр задан, то из всех модулей, которые были найдены в первом пункте, будут выбраны только этот модуль и все модули, от которых он [зависит](https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/Modules/#depends).

   С помощью этого параметра можно удобно управлять набором необходимых модулей для текущего проекта/конфигурации.

Более подробно про этот процесс можно почитать в [документации](https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/Projects).

По итогу, чтобы добавить новый модуль в проект, вам нужно положить его по одному из путей, в которых будет происходить поиск .lsf файлов и, если установлен параметр запуска `logics.topModule`, то прописать его в инструкции `REQUIRE` какого-нибудь из модулей проекта (чаще всего в модуле, прописанном в `logics.topModule`).